# Invalid file format when attempting to read Excel 2007 files in PHP

Tags: php, excel-2007

I am trying to read data from Excel 2003 but I want the system also to load Excel 2007 files. However Excel 2007 file is triggering the file format exception. The code that checks the format is here

```
if ($this->header ['ident'] != "\xD0\xCF\x11\xE0\xA1\xB1\x1A\xE1")
        throw new compoundDocumentException ('Invalid file format');
```

In this line I would like to add the header indent for Excel 2007 which I didn't find wherever I tried.

How do I achieve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel 2007 files (`.XLSX` files) use [a completely different XML-based format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) from previous versions of Excel. Simply checking for a new header will not help you at all here -- you will need an entirely different file reader for these newer files.